# For $n \ge 2$ , does every linear operator on $\mathbb R^n$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $2$ ?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Is it true that for $n \ge 2$ , every linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb R^n$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $2$ ? I know that $T$ always either have a $1$ or $2$ dimensional invariant subspace ; but cannot determine whether it will always have a $2$ dimensional one . Please   help .

Comment: Consider Jordan blocks. Alternatively, if you have two $1$-dimensional subspaces, you can take their sum.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: But does $T$ necessarily have two $1$ dimensional invariant subspace ?

Comment: Try to assume it only has one and see what happens.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on Najib Idrissi’s comment :

The answer is YES. Indeed, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_T$ of $T$ can be factorized over $\mathbb R$ as

$$
\chi_T(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{s} (x-\lambda_k)^{s_k} \prod_{j=1}^t ((x-a_j)^2+b_j^2)
$$

where $\sum_{k=1}^{s} s_k+2t=n$, all $\lambda_k,a_j,b_j$ real, $\lambda_{k}\neq \lambda_{k'}$ when $k\neq k'$, and $b_j\neq 0$ for each $j$.

If $s\geq 2$, then as Najib noted taking an eignevector $e_1$ for $\lambda_1$
and an eigenvector $e_2$ for $\lambda_2$, considering the two-dimensional
space ${\textsf{span}}(e_1,e_2)$ we are done.

Similarly, if $t\geq 1$, $a_j+b_ji$ is a complex eigenvalue for $T$, so there
is a complex eigenvector $u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ have real coordinates.
The eigenidentity $T(u+iv)=(a_j+ib_j)(u+iv)$ yields $Tu=a_ju-b_jv$ and
$Tv=b_ju+a_jv$. It follows that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent and that
the subspace ${\textsf{span}}(u,v)$ is invariant by $T$.

So if $T$ has no two-dimensional invariant subspace, we must have
$s<2,t<1$, and hence

$$
\chi_T(x)=(x-\lambda)^{s_1}
$$

for some $\lambda\in {\mathbb R}$.

If $W_1={\sf Ker}(T-\lambda{\textsf{id}})$ has dimension at least $2$, then
any two-dimensional subspace of $W_1$ will satisfy us. So we can assume
that $W_1$ has dimension $1$, $W_1={\textsf{span}}(e_1)$ for some vector
$e_1$. Consider now $W_2={\sf Ker}((T-\lambda{\textsf{id}})^2)$. If $W_2=W_1$, then $W_{p+1}=W_p$ for every $p \geq 1$ (indeed, if $w\in W_{p+1}$ then $w'=(T-\lambda{\textsf{id}})^{p-1}(w)\in W_2$, so $w'\in W_1$ and hence $w\in W_p$) 
so ${\sf Ker}((T-\lambda{\textsf{id}})^p)=W_1$ for every $p$,  and hence ${\mathbb R}^n={\sf Ker}((T-\lambda{\textsf{id}})^{s_1})=W_1$ which 
is impossible if $n>1$. So $W_1\neq W_2$. Since $W_1$ is a subspace of
$W_2$, we see that there is a vector $e_2\in W_2\setminus W_1$. We have
$(T-\lambda {\sf id})e_2\in W_1$ by definition of $W_1$ and $W_2$, so 
${\textsf{span}}(e_1,e_2)$ is invariant by $T$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: In the $s \ge 2$ case, how do you know that $\mathrm{span}(e1, e2)$ is two-dimensional? (E.g., what if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$?)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Can you explain why ${\sf Ker}((f-\lambda{\textsf{id}})^p)=W_1$ for every $p$? I understood that by induction we need to prove that $W_p=W_1$. The direction $W_1 \subset W_p$ is easy to prove. How about $W_p \subset W_1$?

Comment: @user please see my little update

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thank you. I had a bit different exaplanation for that. Set $T=f-\lambda{\textsf{id}}$ and we wanna show that $W_{p+1} \subset W_1$ with the hypothesis induction that $W_p=W_1, \forall p \ge 1.$ Let $v \in W_{p+1} \implies T^{p+1}(v)=0\implies T(v) \in W_p=W_1$. Therefore, $T^2(v)=0$ hence $v \in W_2=W_1$. In short, $v \in W_1$. This proves the claim.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy. I have two more quick questions. First, what did you mean about the notation $f$ in the last paragraph? Did it mean the transformation $T$? Second, why $\mathbb R^n=\text{Ker}((f−\lambda id)^{s_1})$? Please confirm.

Comment: @user ${\mathbb R}^n={\textsf{Ker}}((T-\lambda \textsf{id})^{s_1})$ by the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)