# A linear application $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ has always an $f$-invariant plane

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, alternative-proof

I hope the question is not a duplicate. Let me know if that's the case.

I found the following exercise in a linear algebra exercise book:

> **Exercise :** Let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ a linear
> application. Prove that exists a vector subspace $\pi$ of
> $\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $2$ such that $f(\pi) \subseteq \pi$.

The latter is relatively simple using Jordan canonical form. I know for sure an other awesome proof involving linear algebra. To you the pleasure of discovering it.

I was wondering whether there were other proofs involving linear algebra or other advanced theory, so I'm asking if you know other proofs of the problem.

**Edit:** To answer Martin in the comments: No it doesn't. I do know two proofs of the facts. What I'm asking for are alternative proofs just for the sake of the pleasure of discovering new proofs of probably one of the most inspiring exercises of linear algebra I've ever done. The question was inspired from a friend of mine, who originally wanted to solve the problem analytcally, or through theorems such as Borsuk-Ulam for example.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3915991/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433629/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/991719/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I've made an edit to make the question clearer, thanks.

Comment: @jacopoburelli I would suggest that you let this one be closed as a duplicate. IMO it is not appropriate if some answers are here and some answers are there. The point of marking duplicates is to have all the answers, interesting or not, in one place. We can do something : I or you can bounty , using my reputation, the duplicate question, and we can bring it to the bountied queue where it is likely to attract more attention. Either you can provide a bounty text or you can let me know what text you want me to provide. I can volunteer for the bounty, but I think splitting the proofs is not right

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Okay I agree, if you want to put the bounty I'm happy with it but if you want to guide me through the process would be great.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Sure. Let me be of service : once you visit [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068514/a-linear-map-t-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr3-has-a-two-dimensional-invariant) question, underneath the post, you will see the text "Start a bounty". Once you click on it, you will get to offer some reputation, then you can offer a custom reason (I am confused, you can choose any of the reasons) then you'll have to write a custom message, I'd say along the lines of your "Edit:" text in the post above, that's great. Your question will get attention instantly.

Comment: Once you're done, since this question is a duplicate, we will close it (and maybe ask the answerer below to post their answer to the duplicate if it isn't already there) and wait for answers on the other page.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I should have done it, let me know, thanks.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Thank you very much. I would assume this is standard procedure : if you want more answers to a question that is a dupe, you can offer a bounty on the duplicated question with a request for better answers. You will get some profitable discussion and good answers out of it hopefully. Thanks, I'll proceed to close this, but +1 for your cooperation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon My pleasure

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Yes, indeed the stated purpose of a bounty is to bring more attention to a particular question.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for the confirmation, it was good that we were able to sort this one out.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the dual linear map
$$
f^t : \text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb R) \longrightarrow \text{Hom}(\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R), \qquad g\mapsto f^t(g) = g\circ f
$$
This map has an eingenvector $g\in \text{Hom}(\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R)$ different from $0$. The kernel of $g$ is a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ and it is easy to show that $f\left(\ker(g)\right) \subseteq \ker(g)$.

Comment: This is the other proof I know, thanks

Comment: @jacopoburelli: And that is another problem with your question: You “know” some proofs but don't tell them,  so that other people waste their time. This is not a puzzling site.

Comment: Could you so gentle to post your answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068514/a-linear-map-t-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr3-has-a-two-dimensional-invariant?